# Printing tensorflow matrix A.eval() changes the matrix's transpose value

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have the following piece of code :

```
def gram_matrix(A):
    """
    Argument:
    A -- matrix of shape (n_C, n_H*n_W)

    Returns:
    GA -- Gram matrix of A, of shape (n_C, n_C)
    """
    #print(A.eval())  --> Line#1
    #print(tf.transpose(A).eval())  ---> Line#2
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈1 line)
    GA = tf.matmul(A, tf.transpose(A))
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return GA
```

The above method is called by the following :

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session() as test:
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    A = tf.random_normal([3, 2*1], mean=1, stddev=4)
    GA = gram_matrix(A)

    print("GA = \n" + str(GA.eval()))
```

At this point everything works fine.

Now if I uncomment both Line#1 and Line#2, I get incorrect value at Line#2 and hence the incorrect value of GA.

If I uncomment only Line#2, I get correct value at Line#2, but still a different and incorrect value of GA.

Why is this happening? Is there a basic TensorFlow concept that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: In TensorFlow if I remember correctly, eval() is a shortcut for calling the run() method, and transpose() reverses the shape of an array - i.e. it turns a 5x4 array into a 4x5 array. So yes, commenting either of those functions out would absolutely change your final value of GA, since you use A to determine GA. Is this what you are confused about? (Sorry if not understanding this correctly, I last used TF in a research position two years ago and I'm very rusty.)

Comment: I am confused about the fact that simply printing A and transpose of A is changing the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lehar,

When you uncomment those lines, you make extra call of `eval()` which inserts next random value of `A`. Try the example below - you will see 2 different values of `A` printed.

```
with tf.Session() as test:
tf.random.set_seed(1)
A = tf.random.normal([3, 2*1], mean=1, stddev=4)
print('A1',A.eval(), '\n')
print('A2',A.eval())

A1 [[ 7.8017416   1.2311957 ]
 [ 0.77180636  2.3617501 ]
 [-5.16232     1.8418424 ]] 

A2 [[ 0.19184637 -0.38206506]
 [ 1.3456485  -1.2691848 ]
 [ 4.286291    0.25501275]]
```